# How do i make my discord bot reference and run another python file which webscrapes information and prints the results in chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot isnt recieving the input from chat despite token being right its online and all the obvious stuff

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import subprocess

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = True  # You can adjust these as needed
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def socialblade(ctx):
  print("Socialblade command received")  # Add this line
  subprocess.run(["python", "Scraper.py"])  # Run the Scraper.py script

bot.run('TOKEN')  # Replace with your actual bot token
```

As for the code its referencing, its all crrect and ive run it seperate too that so i know for a fact its this. Also how would i go about asking the user to input another keyword too be passed onto the other file as "username"

I expected a text result but end up with nothing

Comment: why not simply import the file and run the function?

Comment: [`discord.Intents.default`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.default) wont enable `message_content` which is required for your bot to be able to read message contents. If it can't read the contents, it can't know if you issued a command to the bot. You need to enable it explicitly by either using [`discord.Intents.all`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.all) or [`discord.Intents.message_content = True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content)

Comment: To accept arguments, simply add them after `ctx` in your function definition. [docs for discord.py commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)